# A list of the newly created item should be placed on the top or the bottom？(Allows multiple users to view and operation at the same time）

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, design, lists

There are two kinds of schemes.

1. According to the creation time sorting in reverse chronological order(the newly created item at the top).so this creator can easily find the newly created item, but can make the existing item location down even disorder (in the case of card layout),the team other users don't seem to be easy to use(because in the first item may have been pushed down);
2. According to the creation time positive sequence order(the newly created in the bottom).This solution is not good place is that the creator is looking for that item, must have to scroll to the bottom of the page.

Which scheme you think there will be a better user experience? Best can have a theoretical basis.

Have the list layout and the card layout two cases.
[image: card]

[image: list]

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the logic you are using to place the old elements**. If they were arranged from newest (top) to oldest then add the new cards on top. If the newest were on bottom then on bottom. **If you have to choose probably displaying new elements on top makes more sense on desktop**.

- Top: In web pages ScrollTop starts at 0 by default, this means the user can only scroll down. Adding them on top will make the new cards appear in the first visible place and the user doesn't need to scroll to see them.
- Bottom: As the default is scrollTop 0, adding them on bottom would need the user to scroll and an extra message saying that "new cards where added in the bottom". Bottom is the way to go in Mobile messenger apps, for example, where the scrollTop logic is reversed.

So following the previous my suggestions are:

- **"There are X new cards" clickable message**: as StackExchange sites do. When there is new content you add a message where it will appear, and let the user update it on click.
- **A button thats appears if the user is not seeing the former message**. When the button is clicked the browser scrolls where the new content will appear.
- **A button that refreshes the whole list**. If you think it is going to be complex, add a button that tells the number of new cards and when clicked it refreshes the list.

---

This being said this looks like reversed top and bottom. I followed the logic of the premise that newer elements belong to the bottom. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: COOL ! I also think the StackExchange is very good 